# How can I mass update my favorites in Codeplex Terminals?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm on a laptop and often move back and forth between having monitors and having my built-in monitor, which are obviously at different resolutions. This is a problem for my Codeplex Terminals which stretches the window by default. I have about 50 links that I don't want to go change manually. How can I mass update these to a set resolution? I would assume this is stored in a text file somewhere, but I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Using Process Monitor from SysInternals, I was able to find a handle to a folder called `%appdata%\..\Local\Robert_Chartier\Terminals\Data`. (A quick google search reveals Robert Chartier to be a developer of Terminals.)

From there I opened Favorites.xml and changed all lines of `<DesktopSize>AutoScale</DesktopSize>` to `<DesktopSize>x1024</DesktopSize>` (which was what I found when I did the one manually).

Opening terminals now, I find the size to be appropriate and functioning properly.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell is nice for stuff like this.

**Back up the file first!**

If you want a powershell one-liners:

**This requires Powershell v3 or greater:**

```
(gc 'C:\Path\to\your\file\favorites.xml').Replace("AutoSize","x1024") | Set-Content 'C:\Path\to\your\file\favorites.xml'
```

**This only requires Powershell v2 which you almost certainly have:**

```
(gc 'C:\Path\to\your\file\favorites.xml') -Replace "AutoSize","x1024" | Set-Content 'C:\Path\to\your\file\favorites.xml'
```

Comment: That is great to keep in my back pocket. The real problem was figuring out where the stupid file is in the first place. Ironically, I posted the question and said dammit, what would I do if someone posted this question and I tried to solve it, which led me to open proc mon, follow the file handles, and go from there :)